# How to get data from one table based on a column from another table?

Tags: sql, join

I have two tables, sample data below

```
 tblID (ID, Quantity, Project, Region, Date)
 tblAltID(ID, AltID)
```

tblID

| ID | Quantity | Project | Region | Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 1 | 1 | US | 08-09-2022 |

tblAltID

| ID | AltID |
| --- | --- |
| 123 | [456,789] |

I want to be able to search for a specific 'ID' and have it bring up the data for the 'AltID', this is what I have so far (The alternate IDs in this table are formatted like "[123, 456, 789]")

```
    Select a.ID, b.AltID, a.Quantity, a.Project, a.Region, a.Date

    From tblID as a

    Inner Join (Select ID, AltID From tblAltID CROSS JOIN UNNEST(AltID)) as b on a.ID 
    = b.ID

    Where ID = '123'
    and Date = (Select max(Date) from tblID

    Order By Quantity Desc
```

For example the ID is '123', its alternates are '456' and '789', I need to obtain the quantity, project, region, and date for 123, 456, and 789. Should look something like this ->

| ID | AltID | Quantity | Project | Region | Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | null | 1 | 3 | US | 08-09-2022 |
| 123 | 456 | 1 | 1 | US | 08-09-2022 |
| 123 | 789 | 2 | 2 | Europe | 08-09-2022 |

For reference, all of the alternate IDs also exist in the ID table. So, I could search for ID = 456 and find the quantity, project, region, and date that way. In this example, 123, and 789 would be the alternates.

Comment: Please ask 1 specific researched non-duplicate question. Please either ask about 1 bad query/function with the obligatory [mre] & why you think it should return something else at the 1st subexpression that it doesn't give what you expect justified by reference to authoritative documentation or ask about your overall goal giving working parts you can do & ideally a [mre]. But please ask about the former 1st because misconceptions in the former will get in the way of understanding the latter. And bad code doesn't tell us what you wish it would do. [ask] [Help]

Comment: This is not clear. Use enough words, sentences & references to parts of examples to clearly & fully say what you mean. When giving a business relation(ship)/association or table (base or query result), say what a row in it states about the business situation in terms of its column values. What does that query have to do with your post? Where did the null come from? Please clarify via edits, not comments. PS Relational DB queries do not "search", they calculate the rows that satisfy some condition per a query's conditions & relational operators & the condition satisfied by base table rows.

Answer (score 1):

```
Select a.ID, b.AltID, a.Quantity, a.Project, a.Region, a.Date
From tblID as a

JOIN tblAltId as b ON b.AltId = a.ID
WHERE a.ID = '123'
AND Date = (Select max(Date) from tblID
Order By Quantity Desc
```

Comment: So, this seems very similar to my current code, I did try using just a join instead of an inner join, but I got the same result. The "(Select ID, AltID From tblAltID CROSS JOIN UNNEST(AltID)" is necessary because the current AltID table is formatted weird -> column 1 (ID) = 123, column 2 (AltID) = [456, 789]

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You Could use simple union code if you need only search one time in
your tblAltID. You need to show all records in the tblID where
tblID.ID=123 and also show all records related to the tblAltID where
tblAltID.ID = 123 and  in this case the query should consider that the join condition between tblAltID and tblID is tblAltID.AltID = tblID.ID  to show the all info related to the alt IDs as the following code sample:

```
Select t1.ID, t1.Quantity, t1.Project, t1.Region, t1.Date 
From tblID t1
where t1.ID = 123

union 

Select t1.ID, t1.Quantity, t1.Project, t1.Region, t1.Date
From  tblID t1
inner join (Select ID, AltID From tblAltID CROSS JOIN UNNEST(AltID)) t2 
on t1.ID = t2.AltID
where t2.ID = 123
```

Or you can use the following cte code too:

```
;with cte (ID, Quantity,Project,Region,Date, ALtID) As (
    Select t1.ID, t1.Quantity, t1.Project, t1.Region, t1.Date, t2.AltID
    From  tblID t1
    left join (Select ID, AltID From tblAltID CROSS JOIN UNNEST(AltID)) 
    t2  on t1.ID = t2.ID
    where t1.ID = 123
    
    union All
    select t1.ID, t1.Quantity, t1.Project, t1.Region, t1.Date,null as 
    AltID
    from  tblID t1
    inner join cte c on t1.ID = c.AltID 
    )
    
    Select * 
    from cte t
```

Comment: Ok this looks like exactly what I need, however I am running into one small issue. Anytime I try to use WITH, I get an unexpected tokens [EOF] error. Do you know anything about this?

Comment: Check these points please:

if you are using cte middle of your query and your code is not started with your cte syntax, you need to put ; (semicolon) before with.
;with cte as ()...

after using cte you could only use it only 1 time.

all the fields inside of cte need to be have a name and you could not have duplication.


if these are not your issue please send your error text or your code sample

Comment: because you just need to search alttblID one time.
you could just use a simple union to get your result too. 
I edited my answer and added that code too.

Comment: Hi thanks for helping out btw, the problem with the first query (union query) is the first and second part return the same result for quantity, project, region, and date. The second part of the query (after union) should return the quantity, project, region, and date for the AltID, but it is still returning those values for the ID

Comment: Hi, you are welcome. I have tested that it would not show the same info. please check the join condition in the second part( after union) : (tblID.ID = tblAltID.AltID) and the where condition in tblAltID.ID = 123

Comment: I added more description to my code please try the code with the exact condition that is working. if you have any further questions please let me know.